# Generate and plot the empirical joint pdf and CDF

Tags: matlab, stochastic-process

Given a pair of two variables (X,Y), how can you generate and plot the empirical joint PDF and CDF in vanilla MATLAB (no toolboxes)?

Comment: What do you mean by "empirical joint pdf" ?

Comment: ok, so I used google: empirical joint probability density function!

Comment: how are these variables related? I think we need more information here.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 The statistical relationship between the variables doesn't need to be known in advance; rather, will be a _result_ that can be observed from the computed PDF and CDF

Comment: right, I do not know what I was thinking. nevermind disregard my comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Original answer (Matlab R2015a or lower)

The data are:

- The random variables X, Y: defined as vectors of samples `X`, `Y`.
- The bin edges at the x, y axes: defined by vectors `x_axis`, `y_axis`. The edges must obviously be increasing, but need not be uniformly spaced.

The resulting PDF and CDF are defined at the centers of the rectangles determined by the x and y edges.

To plot the results in 3D, use `surf(...)` instead of `imagesc(...)`.

```
clear all

%// Data (example):
X = randn(1,1e5); %// random variables.
Y = randn(1,1e5);

x_axis = -3:.2:3; %// Define edges of bins for x axis. Column vector
y_axis = -3:.2:3; %// Same for y axis

%// Compute corners of 2D-bins:
[x_mesh_upper,y_mesh_upper] = meshgrid(x_axis(2:end),y_axis(2:end));
[x_mesh_lower,y_mesh_lower] = meshgrid(x_axis(1:end-1),y_axis(1:end-1));

%// Compute centers of 1D-bins:
x_centers = (x_axis(2:end)+x_axis(1:end-1))/2;
y_centers = (y_axis(2:end)+y_axis(1:end-1))/2;

%// Compute pdf:
pdf = mean( bsxfun(@le, X(:), x_mesh_upper(:).') ...
    & bsxfun(@gt, X(:), x_mesh_lower(:).') ...
    & bsxfun(@le, Y(:), y_mesh_upper(:).') ...
    & bsxfun(@gt, Y(:), y_mesh_lower(:).') );
pdf = reshape(pdf,length(x_axis)-1,length(y_axis)-1); %// pdf values at the
%// grid points defined by x_centers, y_centers
pdf = pdf ./ (y_mesh_upper-y_mesh_lower) ./ (x_mesh_upper-x_mesh_lower);
%// normalize pdf to unit integral

%// Compute cdf:
cdf = mean( bsxfun(@le, X(:), x_mesh_upper(:).') ...
    & bsxfun(@le, Y(:), y_mesh_upper(:).') );
cdf = reshape(cdf,length(x_axis)-1,length(y_axis)-1);

%// Plot pdf
figure
imagesc(x_centers,y_centers,pdf)
axis xy
axis equal
colorbar
title 'pdf'

%// Plot cdf
figure
imagesc(x_centers,y_centers,cdf)
axis xy
axis equal
colorbar
title 'cdf'
```

[image: PDF]
[image: CDF]

## Edited answer (Matlab R2015b or higher)

Matlab R2015b includes an [`histogram2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram2.html) function that does all the work. It automatically does the normalization to obtain the PDF (given the appropriate input flag), or even the CDF.

Using the same example as above,

```
clear all

%// Data (example):
X = randn(1,1e5); % random variables.
Y = randn(1,1e5);

x_axis = -3:.2:3; % Define edges of bins for x axis. Column vector
y_axis = -3:.2:3; % Same for y axis

%// Compute and plot pdf
figure
histogram2(X, Y, x_axis, y_axis, 'Normalization', 'pdf')

%// Compute and plot cdf
figure
histogram2(X, Y, x_axis, y_axis, 'Normalization', 'cdf')
```

[image: PDF, R2010b]
[image: CDF, R2015b]