# How to efficiently find and merge duplicate enteries of a vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sorting, unique

I am writing a MATLAB code to quickly solve the following problem: Let X be a random variable distributed according to P(x), take two independent copies of X, call them X1 and X2 and find the distribution of Y = f(X1,X2) where f(,) is a known function.

To solve the above, I start with two vectors `x` and `p` such that `p(i)` = P(`x(i)`). Suppose they both contain `n` elements. I can easily compute the `n`-by-`n` matrix `y` such that `y(i,j)` = f(`x(i)`, `x(j)`). Furthermore, I can compute the `n`-by-`n` matrix `p_out` such that `p_out(i,j) = p(i) * p(j)`. This means P(Y = `y(i,j)`) = `p(i,j)`.

Now, if all elements of `y` are distinct we are almost done. It remains just converting the matrices to vectors and perhaps sorting them to have a nice output. Suppose we also do this by setting

```
y = y(:);
p_out = p_out(:);
[y, idx] = sort(y);
p_out = p_out(idx);
```

The problem is, however, the elements of `y` are not typically unique. I, hence, have to merge the identical elements of `y` as follows: if `y(i) = y(j)` (remember now `y` is converted to a vector) then remove `y(j)` and set `p(i) = p(i) + p(j)`. A dirty way of doing this is using a for loop (since `y` is now sorted we only need to compare each element with its following element). However, I wonder if there exits a nicer way.

I know that `unique` would remove the duplicated elements of a vector (hence if we only needed `y` it would be sufficient). I also know that it returns two index vectors that somehow indicate the position of duplicated elements. However, I cannot think of any nice way to use its outputs to **appropriately** merge the elements of `p` as well.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639518/generate-and-plot-the-empirical-joint-pdf-and-cdf-in-matlab

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. I guess that is a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a job for [`accummarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
y = [1 3 2 4 2 5 6 5 5 1]; %// example data
p = [.1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .1 .1 .2 .1 .3]; %// example data

[y_unique ii jj] = unique(y);
p_summed = accumarray(jj.',p).';
```

Result:

```
>> y_unique

y_unique =

     1     2     3     4     5     6

p_summed =

    0.4000    0.7000    0.5000    0.2000    0.4000    0.1000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was exactly looking for such a function!

Comment: This `unique`/`accumarray` usage is perhaps my favorite MATLAB idiom. +1

Comment: @chappjc It would be nice if it could be combined into a single line, for example if the desired output of `unique` was the first, not the third

Comment: Nah, I think two lines is just fine!