# How can I make a probability density contour plot of 3d data?

Tags: matlab, 3d, probability, contour, scatter

I have a XxYxZ array of data.

I generate a XxY scatter plot and then overlay them all for each Z.

But of course, this looks messy and all of the data points are on top of each other. I want to make a contour plot, showing probability density for the scattered data.

```
% A is a XxY matrix
for ii = length(A)
figure(1)
plot(A,squeeze(B(:,:,ii)),'o')
hold on
xlabel('A')
ylabel('B')
end
```

So how do I take the XxYxZ matrix B and XxY matrix A and plot the scatter plot of B and A at each Z onto a 2d probability density contour plot?

This is what I have...
[image]

This is the kind of thing I'm going for....

[image: figure]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639518/generate-and-plot-the-empirical-joint-pdf-and-cdf) is a little messy, but may give you some ideas

Comment: please post your example data, respectively runnable code of what you have.

Comment: How many distinct values of Z are there? Is Z a categorical or continuous variable?