# How to create 3D Histogram with Percentage on Z Axis

Tags: matlab, 3d, histogram, percentage

I want to create 3D histogram with percentages on Z axis. I used hist3 function, but it only creates histogram with frequency on Z axis. Can someone please help me to change frequency to percentage in the hist3 function?

Comment: I guess you will have to use N = hist3(X,...) to first normalize your Z axis into percentage before plotting it again using hist3(...,param1,val1,param2,val2,...)

Comment: Quite interesting. I must admit I first though this question was too simple for SO. However when looking into it, this turned out to be quite a mess. The best way may actually be to do as said in [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824686/how-to-create-3d-histogram-with-percentage-on-z-axis#comment53486024_32824686). It would also work to edit the function `hist3` but this would most certainly lead to complications later. Anyway, it is a shame it must be so hard.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639518/generate-and-plot-the-empirical-joint-pdf-and-cdf) what you want?

Comment: I guess I would go with a bar3 plot, computing the stuff by myself.