# How to plot pdf from given samples of multivariate distribution

Tags: matlab, plot

I have multivariate samples with dimension $N$ How to plot the pdf in matlab from these samples? I tried using hist but it gives plot only for one dimension.

Comment: i don't understand, what you want after all, but to plot to pdf you should check out [save2pdf Matlab FileExchange](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16179-save2pdf)

Comment: Check out [`pdf`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdf.html) or [`mvnpdf`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html). It requires Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox

Comment: For _N_ = 2 check `histogram2` or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639518/generate-and-plot-the-empirical-joint-pdf-and-cdf-in-matlab). For _N_ > 2, how would you do the plot?