# calculate histogram of 2 variables

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a vector containining the speed of 200 walks:

```
a = 50;
b = 100;
speed = (b-a).*rand(200,1) + a;
```

and another vector contaning the number of steps for each walk:

```
a = 8;
b = 100;
steps = (b-a).*rand(200,1) + a;
```

I would like to create a histogram plot with on the x axis the speeds and on the y axes the sum of the steps of each speed.

What I do is the following but I guess there is a more elegant way to do this:

```
unique_speed = unique(speed);
y_unique_speed  = zeros(size(unique_speed));
for i = 1 : numel(unique_speed)

    speed_idx = unique_speed(i);
    idx = speed==speed_idx ;
    y_unique_speed  (i) = sum(steps (idx));

end
```

Comment: With the code you give here,  it is very unlikely that 2 `speed` values will be equal. Are they generated the same way in your actual code?

Comment: No I have real data.....

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18640944/2586922)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to discretize your `speed` variable. Unlike in the other answer, the following allows you to choose arbitrary step size, e.g. I've chosen `1.5`. Note that the last bin edge should be strictly more than the maximum data point, hence I used `max(speed)+binstep`. You can then use `histc` to determine which bin each pairs falls into, and `accumarray` to determine total number of steps in each bin. Finally, use `bar` to plot.

```
binstep = 1.5;
binranges = (min(speed):binstep:max(speed)+binstep)';
[~, ind] = histc(speed, binranges);
bincounts = accumarray(ind, steps, size(binranges));
hFig = figure(); axh = axes('Parent', hFig); hold(axh, 'all'); grid(axh, 'on');
bar(axh, binranges, bincounts); axis(axh, 'tight');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, bin the speed data to discrete values:

```
sspeed = ceil(speed);
```

and then accumulate the various step sizes to each bin:

```
numsteps = accumarray(sspeed, steps);
plot(numsteps)
```